# How to mogrify recursive folders compacting the files

Tags: linux, recursion, find, command, mogrify

I need to excute in ubuntu something like this:

```
find ./ -name '*.jpg' -execdir "mogrify -quality 50 *.jpg" {} \;
```

To compact all the *.jpg to 50% of your quality but this need to be recursive, because i have 1350 files in a long tree of folders...

And this return ever something like:

```
mogrify: unable to open image `Banner-Caixa.jpg': permission denied @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2712.
```

Comment: Does the user executing the find command have permission to read the files?

Comment: yes because "find . -name "*.jpg" " works!

Comment: If you can execute find on a directory it does not mean you can open the file. To see which files exist you meed read permissions on the directory, to actually read the files you need the read permission on the actual file.

Comment: hmm, this make sense, tsk man

Answer (score 10):

I discovered!

```
sudo find . -name '*.jpg' -execdir sh -c "mogrify -quality 50 *.jpg" {} \;
```

This works fine!

widoth `/` on `./` and add `sh -c` after `-execdir`

Comment: Thanks! However, you might not need sudo if files are owned by you.

Comment: are you sûre about this command, I gues the ending *.jpg make mogrify look deeply each time
I use this one and it works fine:

find . -name '*.jpg' -execdir sh -c "mogrify -quality 50 {} " \;

Comment: The last *.jpg produces a error:
Take  sudo find . -name '*.jpg' -execdir sh -c "mogrify -quality 50 {}"  \;